# How do I run the social timer jobs in powershell?

Tags: powershell, timer-jobs, social, rating

As title says. I've applied ratings to documents and they, obviously, haven't appeared yet. Is it possible to use powershell to explicitly force these timer jobs to run immediately?

I believe the relevant timer jobs are:

**Social Rating Synchronisation Job**

**Social Data Maintenance Job**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-SPTimerJob | Select DisplayName, Name | Sort Name
```

Will get you all installed timer jobs

The two in question are called

User Profile Service Application - Social Data Maintenance Job
(User Profile Service Application_SocialDataMaintenanceJob)

User Profile Service Application - Social Rating Synchronization Job 
(User Profile Service Application_SocialRatingSyncJob)

If you want to activate those jobs by PowerShell use the following syntax:

```
Get-SPTimerJob | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*_social*"} | Start-SPTimerJob
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger SharePoint timer job using PowerShell as:

```
#Display name of the Timer Job to Run on-demand
$TimerJobName = "User Profile SA - Social Rating Synchronization Job"

#Get the Timer Job
$TimerJob = Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.DisplayName -match $TimerJobName}

#start the timer job
Start-SPTimerJob $TimerJob
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/08/how-to-run-timer-job-manually-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell.html

Comment: So, exactly the same answer as @Anders Rask gave?

Answer (score 1):

Start-SPTimerJob does not run the job immediately, it starts the job and it will run according to schedule. You should use RunNow() if you want to run the job immediately.

`$TimerJob = Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.DisplayName -eq "User Profile SA - Social Rating Synchronization Job"}`

`$TimerJob.RunNow()`

I do not recommend using "-like" to get timerjobs to run or activate. This could lead to unforeseen issues. If you just want to list timerjobs "-like" is ok.